# How to include a wrapper element if there are items in a collection?

Tags: reactjs

I'm obviously not doing this the React way.

- I have a collection of comparison objects that are shown
- if there is more than one, then I want to include a wrapper element around this collection

In Vue.js I would do this with a `v-show` or `v-if` for instance. How do I do this in React?

[image]

```
{/* COMPARISONS */}
{this.getCurrentItem().comparisons!.length > 0 &&
    (
        <div className="comparisonAreas"> 
    )
}
{
    this.getCurrentItem().comparisons!.map((comparison: IComparison) => {
        return (
            <div className="comparison">
                <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.getSmartVersusLine(comparison, this.getCurrentItem()) }} />
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.convertComparisonBodyToBodyParsed(comparison) }} />
            </div>
        )
    })
}
{this.getCurrentItem().comparisons!.length > 0 &&
    (
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the middle into a variable before and then render the two cases:

```
const MyComp = (props) => {
  const comparisonObjects = ...
  if(comparisionObjects.length <= 1) {
     return comparisonObjects 
  } else {
    return <div>{comparisonObjects}</div>;
  }
}
```

Edit: You should add a `key` prop in your array components. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator :

```
{this.getCurrentItem().comparisons!.length>0 ?
<div className="comparisonAreas">getCurrentItem.comparisons!.map...</div>
: getCurrentItem.comparisons!.map...
}
```